# Using a Radar Sensor

Tags: c#, sensors

I have been experimenting with depth sensors using IR but they have been sadly lacking in accuracy (at least for what I want) and range.

So, looking for alternatives.

The application is I am holding a rectangular block of plastic and I am sweeping it from left to right across a surface ( a wall in this case ) and I want to know if the gap between plastic surface and wall surface reaches a certain threshold.

I have a web camera attached to a Microsoft Surface and I am aiming this camera at this user motion.

If I had better quality image I am sure I could use basic geometry to work this out.  I looking around for better cameras as I type...

I was considering a radar sensor instead.

I spent many hours yesterday looking for something like a usb radar sensor with a SDK that is friendly for usage with C#.

I have not found anything.

That is not to say I have given up. I am continuing to look.

I just thought I would post here as well for any ones ideas on this?

i will continue to update my questions with hopefully a solution if no one else does.

thanks

Comment: My father always said when spackling a wall find the largest pallet you can which would give a flat surface and minimize the sanding.  A human person and a block of wood is not going to give you  great accuracy.  Trying to make a measurement to an accuracy better then the tolerances is crazy.Where can you find these days a flat piece of wood?Then trying to have a person hold the device flat against the wall is again error prone.Then you eye looking at the flat wall wouldn't even see if it wasn't flat.I know you need a flat surface to hand wall paper, but don't make your specification to tight.

Comment: @jdweng Hi thanks for your comment.  These are not my specifications but the clients. I have never been asked to do such a thing before.  When presented with this problem I expressed the same opnion as you.  I used the wood anology but in reality it is a probe which is flat and is made out of plastic. The client is only concerned with the space between this plastic and the surface.  The wall not being completely flat is not a bearing then in this case.  But my fault I should not have mentioned wood and will edit my question accordingly :)

Comment: @jdweng I still agree with the craziness of the plan but I owe it to my client to be objective and report in a couple of days accordingly.

Comment: May be worth asking this on the electronics stack exchange site too

Comment: @Rikalous thanks. I was concerned i was asking on the wrong forum,  Not my field really. I shall leave a for a couple of hours and move across. Thank you

Comment: The flatness is going to vary depending on the area you are checking.  Even the angle you hold plastic is gong to vary.  You may want  to talk to people at Popular Photography Test Lab.  My neighbor used to run the lab.  To test focus of cameras they hung a large test pattern on the wall and compared cameras clarity.  I think if you put a target on the wall then used a laser aimed at each button you can get distances.  Maybe use image recognition software to help.

Comment: @jdweng Thanks for all that :)

Comment: The best you can get is the software that was used to grind the Hubble telescope mirrors.  The accuracy was very precise.